# Reading values from SQLite Database for Google Map Markers

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to read position (Latitude, Longitude) values and a title from a pre-made SQLite database. The problem I'm getting is that it seems to display a Marker on the map, but has nothing to do with the values in the DB - it's almost as if they're being read incorrectly.

My MonumentsDatabase.java class (where I handle the database):

```
public class MonumentsDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static String DATABASE_NAME = "antiquityDatabase.db";
public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.antiquity/databases/";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
int _id;
double _lat;
double _lng;

String _title;
String _date;
String _description;

String[] _idColumn = {"_id"};
String[] latColumn = {"latitude"};
String[] lngColumn = {"longitude"};
String[] titleColumn = {"title"};
String[] dateColumn = {"date"};
String[] descColumn = {"description"};


private SQLiteDatabase database;
private final Context myContext;

public MonumentsDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}

public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean databaseExist = checkDatabase();

    if(databaseExist) {
        //Do nothing
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDatabase();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDatabase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDatabase = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        //database doesnt exist yet
    }

    if(checkDatabase != null) {
        checkDatabase.close();
    }

    return checkDatabase != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    String outputFilename = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {

    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public int getID() { 
    Cursor idQuery = database.query("monuments", _idColumn, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (idQuery.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int columnsQty = idQuery.getColumnCount();
            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                sb.append(idQuery.getString(idx));
                if (idx < columnsQty - 1)
                    sb.append("; ");
            }
            Log.v("getID() - ID", String.format("Row: %d, Values: %s", idQuery.getPosition(), sb.toString()));

        }
        while (idQuery.moveToNext());
    }
    return _id;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    _id = id;
}

public double getLat() {
    Cursor latQuery = database.query("monuments", latColumn,  null, null, null, null, null);

    latQuery.moveToFirst();
    if (latQuery.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int columnsQty = latQuery.getColumnCount();
            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                sb.append(latQuery.getString(idx));
                if (idx < columnsQty - 1)
                    sb.append("; ");
            }
            Log.v("getLat() - LATITUDE", String.format("Row: %d, Values: %s", latQuery.getPosition(), sb.toString()));

        }
        while (latQuery.moveToNext());


    }       
    return _lat;
}

public void setLat(double lat) {
    _lat = lat;
}

public double getLng() {
    Cursor lngQuery = database.query("monuments", lngColumn,  null, null, null, null, null);

    if (lngQuery.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int columnsQty = lngQuery.getColumnCount();
            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                sb.append(lngQuery.getString(idx));
                if (idx < columnsQty - 1)
                    sb.append("; ");
            }
            Log.v("getLng() - LONGITUDE", String.format("Row: %d, Values: %s", lngQuery.getPosition(), sb.toString()));

        }
        while (lngQuery.moveToNext());
    }
    return _lng;
}

public void setLng(double lng) {
    _lng = lng;
}
// Handle the monuments titles
public String getTitle() {
    Cursor titleQuery = database.query("monuments", titleColumn,  null, null, null, null, null);

    if (titleQuery.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int columnsQty = titleQuery.getColumnCount();
            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                sb.append(titleQuery.getString(idx));
                if (idx < columnsQty - 1)
                    sb.append("; ");
            }
            Log.v("getTitle() - TITLE", String.format("Row: %d, Values: %s", titleQuery.getPosition(), sb.toString()));

        }
        while (titleQuery.moveToNext());
    }
    return _title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    _title = title;
}

public String getDate() {
    Cursor dateQuery = database.query("monuments", dateColumn, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (dateQuery.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int columnsQty = dateQuery.getColumnCount();
            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                sb.append(dateQuery.getString(idx));
                if (idx < columnsQty - 1)
                    sb.append("; ");
            }
            Log.v("getDate() - DATE", String.format("Row: %d, Values: %s", dateQuery.getPosition(), sb.toString()));

        }
        while (dateQuery.moveToNext());
    }
    return _date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {

    _date = date;
}

public String getDescription() {
    Cursor descriptionQuery = database.query("monuments", descColumn, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (descriptionQuery.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int columnsQty = descriptionQuery.getColumnCount();
            for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                sb.append(descriptionQuery.getString(idx));
                if (idx < columnsQty - 1)
                    sb.append("; ");
            }
            Log.v("getDescription() - DESCRIPTION", String.format("Row: %d, Values: %s", descriptionQuery.getPosition(), sb.toString()));

        }
        while (descriptionQuery.moveToNext());

    }
    return _description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    _description = description;
}

public void addMarker(MarkerObject m) {
    m.getTitle();

}

public ArrayList<MonumentsDatabase> arrayDB() {
    ArrayList<MonumentsDatabase> aD = new ArrayList<MonumentsDatabase>();
    //aD.add(getTitle());

    return aD;
}
```

}

My MainActivity.java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap map;
Intent data;    
MonumentsDatabase monDatabase;
ArrayList<MonumentsDatabase> mDatabase;
int _id;
double _lat;
double _lng;
double sLat;
double sLng;
String _title;
String titles;
double lats;
double lngs;
LatLng markerPosition;
int i;
private Marker bigBen;
private Marker mainMarker;
private Marker parliamentSQ;
private Marker parliament;
private Marker random;


static final LatLng PARLIAMENT = new LatLng(51.499776600000000000, -0.125173099999983600);
//static final LatLng MARKERS = new LatLng(getLatitude(), getLongitude());
static final LatLng PARLIAMENTSQ = new LatLng(51.5006, -0.1267);
static final LatLng RANDOM = new LatLng(51.5019, -0.1257);
LocationManager locationManager;
Context context = this;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
           Intent data = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayData.class);
           startActivity(data);

        }
    });

    ArrayList<MonumentsDatabase> mDB = createDatabase();


    for(i = 0; i < mDB.size(); i++) {
        //Get position of what the DB is and get the latitude and longitude
        sLat = mDB.get(i).getLat();
        sLng = mDB.get(i).getLng();
        markerPosition = new LatLng(sLat, sLng);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(markerPosition)
            .title(mDB.get(i).getTitle())
            .snippet("Click for more info.")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker))); 
    }





    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

    if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
        disabledGPS();
    }       

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}




private void disabledGPS() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder gpsDisabled = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    gpsDisabled.setMessage("This app requires GPS to be enabled. Do you wish to continue?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    AlertDialog mainAlert = gpsDisabled.create();
    mainAlert.show();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public ArrayList<MonumentsDatabase> createDatabase() {
    monDatabase = new MonumentsDatabase(this);
    try {   
        monDatabase.createDatabase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        monDatabase.openDatabase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){ 
        throw sqle;
    }

    mDatabase = new ArrayList<MonumentsDatabase>();
    monDatabase.setTitle(titles);
    monDatabase.setLat(lats);
    monDatabase.setLng(lngs);
    titles = monDatabase.getTitle();
    lats = monDatabase.getLat();
    lngs = monDatabase.getLng();
    mDatabase.add(monDatabase);

    return mDatabase;
}
```

}

What I want to happen is for title, latitude and longitude values read and displayed as Markers on Google Maps, there are currently 20 records in the SQLite database.

Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Log cat prints out the data as so:

```
02-24 12:55:11.691: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 0, Values: Big Ben
02-24 12:55:11.692: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 1, Values: Swansea Castle
02-24 12:55:11.693: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 2, Values: Cardiff Castle
02-24 12:55:11.694: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 3, Values: Mumbles Lighthouse
02-24 12:55:11.695: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 4, Values: Sketty Hall
02-24 12:55:11.695: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 5, Values: St Mary's Church, Swansea
02-24 12:55:11.696: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 6, Values: Loughor
02-24 12:55:11.696: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 7, Values: Oystermouth Castle
02-24 12:55:11.696: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 8, Values: Oxwich Castle
02-24 12:55:11.696: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 9, Values: Penlle'r Castell
02-24 12:55:11.696: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 10, Values: Pennard Castle
02-24 12:55:11.698: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 11, Values: The Palace Theatre
02-24 12:55:11.699: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 12, Values: Morris Castle
02-24 12:55:11.699: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 13, Values: Castle Cinema
02-24 12:55:11.699: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 14, Values: Port Eynon
02-24 12:55:11.700: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 15, Values: Penrice Castle
02-24 12:55:11.700: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 16, Values: Weobley Castle
02-24 12:55:11.700: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 17, Values: St Fagans Castle
02-24 12:55:11.700: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 18, Values: Gregynog Hall
02-24 12:55:11.700: V/getTitle() - TITLE(18411): Row: 19, Values: Margam Castle
02-24 12:55:11.702: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 0, Values: 51.5008
02-24 12:55:11.703: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 1, Values: 51.6203
02-24 12:55:11.703: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 2, Values: 51.4824
02-24 12:55:11.703: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 3, Values: 51.5671
02-24 12:55:11.703: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 4, Values: 51.6131
02-24 12:55:11.704: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 5, Values: 51.619
02-24 12:55:11.704: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 6, Values: 51.6626
02-24 12:55:11.704: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 7, Values: 51.5765
02-24 12:55:11.704: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 8, Values: 51.5546
02-24 12:55:11.705: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 9, Values: 51.7691
02-24 12:55:11.705: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 10, Values: 51.5766
02-24 12:55:11.705: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 11, Values: 51.3739
02-24 12:55:11.705: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 12, Values: 51.391
02-24 12:55:11.705: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 13, Values: 51.3715
02-24 12:55:11.706: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 14, Values: 51.5453
02-24 12:55:11.706: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 15, Values: 51.5752
02-24 12:55:11.706: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 16, Values: 51.6128
02-24 12:55:11.706: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 17, Values: 51.4859
02-24 12:55:11.707: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 18, Values: 52.3403
02-24 12:55:11.707: V/getLat() - LATITUDE(18411): Row: 19, Values: 51.5628
02-24 12:58:56.017: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 0, Values: -0.1247
02-24 12:58:56.018: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 1, Values: 3.9412
02-24 12:58:56.018: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 2, Values: 3.1811
02-24 12:58:56.018: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 3, Values: 3.9723
02-24 12:58:56.018: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 4, Values: 3.9883
02-24 12:58:56.020: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 5, Values: 3.943
02-24 12:58:56.020: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 6, Values: 4.06461
02-24 12:58:56.020: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 7, Values: 4.00297
02-24 12:58:56.020: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 8, Values: 4.16791
02-24 12:58:56.021: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 9, Values: 3.9356
02-24 12:58:56.024: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 10, Values: 4.1023
02-24 12:58:56.025: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 11, Values: 3.5628
02-24 12:58:56.026: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 12, Values: 3.562
02-24 12:58:56.027: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 13, Values: 3.5629
02-24 12:58:56.027: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 14, Values: 4.215
02-24 12:58:56.027: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 15, Values: 4.1703
02-24 12:58:56.027: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 16, Values: 4.1994
02-24 12:58:56.028: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 17, Values: 3.2677
02-24 12:58:56.028: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 18, Values: 3.2108
02-24 12:58:56.029: V/getLng() - LONGITUDE(18567): Row: 19, Values: 3.7254
```

Comment: Could you please log the values of **sLat** and **sLng**, and post as an update to your post so we might see if the values are being retrieved correctly.

Comment: Sure! It's updated with the output :)

Comment: I can only see the Latitude, could you please paste this after the `mDB.get(i).getLng()` line: `Log.i("MainActivity", "Latitude and Longitude " + sLat + " - " + sLng);` and post the new log.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise it didn't attach, it's all up now! :)

Comment: Add this `Log.i("MainActivity", "Latitude and Longitude: " + sLat + " - " + sLng + " - Title: " + mDB.get(i).getTitle());` after the `mDB.get(i).getLng()`, so we might see the values in the correct order, and post the update please.

Comment: Nothings actually being printed, maybe it's a case that they're not even being set as anything? Hmm..

Comment: wait.. if nothing is being printed, from where those values from the previous log were retrieved? Your map object seems fine, I also guess it's related to the values not being set.

Comment: They're being printed out in the actual "getLat()" methods when called, those methods are in MonumentsDatabase

Comment: Can you post the code for those methods `getLat()` and `getLng()`. Also log the content of that list `mDB`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48274/discussion-between-rogcg-and-connor-mcfadden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latitude and longitude are not being retrieved, since the methods `getLat()` and `getLng()` are retrieving it wrong from the cursor.

Since you are selecting only one column from database, you must get the column index 0, and not 1 or 2 as you were doing inside `getLat()` and `getLng()` methods.

Inside those methods, do this:

```
// getLat() method
_lat = latQuery.getDouble(0); 

// getLng() method
_lng = lngQuery.getDouble(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but it looks like your getLat() method doesn't actually set the value of _lat (which is what it returns) anywhere? Similarly for getLong() etc.

If this isn't the issue, have you tried debugging and stepping through the code? That should give you a better idea of where  the duff value is coming from.

Sorry, I would have added this as a comment, but don't have enough rep.

Comment: I'll have a look now, I've sent the DB through the Log and it prints out fine, so maybe that is why!

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason to keep the data tuple - lat, lng, description etc. - apart? I'd put it into a table with 3 columns (cut the rest for brevity):

```
Latitude | Longitude | Description
11.11    | 11.11     | Place A
22.22    | 22.22     | place B
```

In this case you would never get a record like `11,11; 22.22; place B`, what is obviously happening in your case